# Xubuntu 13.10 (Kernel 3.11.0-18-generic) No HDMI Sound

Tags: sound, ati, xubuntu, pulseaudio, hdmi

I am a complete noob to Xubuntu.

I have been trying all day to get HDMI audio to work, I have a Radeon HD 6800 using a HDMI to TV and I can not do it at all.

It shows up in PulseAudio Volume Control as "Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series] Digital Stereo (HDMI)" port = HDMI / DisplayPort

It also shows up when sound is played on that screen (Levels) but no audio is coming out. I have tried nearly all suggested fixes. Its probably really simple to someone who knows but I have tried everything I can to get it to work.

ALSA shows up as 00 - unmuted, but it also says SPDIF - could this be the issue?

Any help appreciated.

If you want me to post any system info up, I would appreciate it if you could tell me what command to put in first. - Complete Noob :D

Comment: Now fixed :D

I finally sorted it using the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1" edit

it was in there but the quiet splash was after the radeon.audio=1 (I didn't do this)

Comment: I have audio but its crackling. I am looking for a solution, if I find one I will update this, if not I would appreciate any help - I have tried lowering the output volume and turning up the TV volume

Comment: yep, thats sorted with - load-module module-hal-detect tsched=0

Comment: Hi- congrats for solving this.  Please come back tomorrow and post an answer to your question.  You'll be able to accept your answer - and hopefully receive some well earned upvotes.

Comment: Will do, I think this site will be well frequented by me in the near future.